# Traduction de « consensus clustering »

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique, mathématiques

Je dois écrire un rapport de stage en français où je dois traduire le terme « consensus clustering ».

J'aurai tendance à utiliser le terme "partitionnement consensuel" cependant la définition mathématique du terme partition ferait penser qu'il vaut mieux utiliser "partition consensuelle".

Laquelle de ces traductions est la plus exacte? Existe-t-il une autre formulation?

Un peu de contexte :

- [*Consensus Clustering Algorithms: Comparison and Refinement*](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/1.9781611972887.11), par Andrey Goder et Vladimir Filkov.
- [Partition (mathématiques)](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28math%C3%A9matiques%29), sur Wikipédia.

Comment: Ton stage traite d'infrastructure informatique ou d'analyse de données ?

Comment: Plutôt analyse de données

Comment: J'aurais tendance a appeler l’opération un _partitionnement_ et le résultat une _partition_, mais il faut noter que les dictionnaires comme le TLFi donnent comme sens premier de [_partition_](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/partition) celui de l’opération -- le résultat n’étant pour eux qu'un usage métonymique -- et ignorent le mot [_partitionnement_](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/partition).

Comment: Peux-tu donner la phrase complète en anglais?

Comment: Je ne connais pas ce terme technique, donc je ne me hasarderai pas à traduire, mais je pense que l'adjectif *consensuel* n'est pas approprié car trompeur. Un *partitionnement consensuel* signifie qu'il y a un consensus sur le choix de la méthode de partitionnement, pas que la méthode de partitionnement fait intervenir une notion de consensus.

Comment: J'ai rien trouvé avec http://www.linguee.fr, il faudrait tomber sur un spécialiste du domaine. (Comme il s'agit d'un rapport de stage, demander à ceux avec qui tu as travaillé me semble être le meilleur moyen de ne pas faire un contre-sens)

Comment: Regroupement hiérarchique ? voir documentation : http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regroupement_hi%C3%A9rarchique.

Comment: Il n'y a pas de hiérarchie entre les éléments. Ici on a un ensemble que l'on a partitionné de différentes manières, et le "consensus clustering" est une sorte de "partition moyenne" entre toutes ces partitions

Answer (score 3):

[[...] méthodes de classification de données (méthode de regroupement hiérarchique ou méthode de partitionnement de données).](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering)

Je pencherais pour **classification par logique classique** *(ou binaire)*

*Consensus* décrit la méthode totalitaire (une donnée **appartient** ou **n'appartient pas** à tel groupe (binaire)), au contraire de [la méthode floue](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logique_floue) où une donnée peut appartenir partiellement à un groupe.

Comment: -1: si tu es certain qu'il s'agit de la formule employée dans le domaine, la rédaction ne l'indique pas assez clairement, si tu n'en es pas certain, il ne faut pas proposer des traductions techniques, le risque de contre-sens est trop élevé.  Pour info, google ne trouve pas d'occurrences de "partitionnement totalitaire", ce qui, combiné avec la généralité de tes références, me fait pencher pour la seconde possibilité.

Comment: @Unfrancophone, J'ai enlevé la traduction erronée. Peut-être  ne comprenais-je pas le but de *stackexchange*, mais n'est-il pas de répondre aux questions, puis que la meilleure question soit votée en haut de la page? Comme explicitement écrit dans le [tour](http://french.stackexchange.com/tour)? Si vous avez bien lu ma réponse, j'ai écris **je pencherais**, cela implique une incertitude. Sinon, j'aurais écris **la traduction de ce terme est**. Éclairez moi sur le fonctionnement de ce site si j'ai tord. Si votre raisonnement serait que ma réponse pourrait causer un contre-sens, je comprendrais.

Comment: Un terme technique a généralement une (parfois plusieurs) traduction acceptée; proposer des traductions sans être du domaine est dangereux.  Les professionnels de la traduction le font trop souvent, au point que j'ai arrêté de lire des traductions d'ouvrage technique parce que les traducteurs avaient parfois une approche trop littéraire, n'utilisant pas les termes établis parce qu'un autre sonnait mieux à leur oreille, variant les traductions pour éviter les répétitions, ... et aboutissant à un texte incompréhensible.